# Imageresizer with Azure CDN

Tags: imageresizer

We have a blob storage in Azure and we also have an azure CDN that points to this blob storage.
How would we configure Imageresizer so that it can work with the CDN.
Currently we have configured Imageresizer in web.config with the connectionstring of the blob storage, but don't know how to change this to work with the CDN.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CDN is a reverse proxy. It knows about ImageResizer, and proxies traffic to it, but ImageResizer doesn't need to know anything about the CDN. No changes are  required to put a CDN in front of server.